# How to append the last 4 letters of every item in a dataframe column to a list

Tags: python, list, append

I have an inventory system with two separate SKUs in a single string, example (FT3M-FL3M), I want to make a list called "first_item" and append the first 4 letters (first SKU) to it and do this for every item in the column.
Then do the same but with taking the last 4 digits of each string (second SKU)

This is the example dataframe

```
| Index    | Skus           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | FT3M-FL3M      |
| Second   | FT2M-FL2M      |
| Second   | FT1M-FB1M      |
| Second   | FT4S-FL4S      |
| Second   | FT4S-FB2M      |
```

This is the code I have:

```
first_list = []
for i in sku:
first_list.append(i[0:4])
print(first_list)
```

It clearly doesn't work and I get a massive list.

Comment: try to avoid looping over entire DataFrames whenever possible because there are faster ways of doing that if your dataset is larger. something like this, if your DataFrame is called "sku": `sku["Skus"].str[:4].tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a list of first / last `n` characters of a string inside a pandas column you can try:

```
# first
my_first = [x[:4] for x in df.wanted_column]

# last
my_last = [x[-4:] for x in df.wanted_column]
```

This gives you a possibility to filter the list on the fly if needed, for example:

```
my_filtered = my_first = [x[:4] for x in df.wanted_column if 'some_sku' not in x]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jonas! That pretty much solves it

Comment: If you are happy with the answer you can upvote & accept it, also you can upvote comments below your question. Happy to help!